# Can I make custom menus in presta shop back office

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've recently decided to give presta shop 1.6 a go. It's quite a lot to take in as I've primarily been working with a custom cms that seems more logical to work with.

What I'm wondering is... Am I able to modify all the navigation menu links in the back office to suit my desired workflow?

I'm finding that in comparison to my own application it's quite complicated and I think I could establish a really nice workflow.

Ideally I'd prefer to not have to code anything, but if there is no other option I would take it on as a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying menu in BO is actually pretty simple.

You just have to go to Administration > Menus and organize it the way you want.